# How to plot graph against index in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The data looks like this:

```
        1       2       3       4
foo             
t0      95      95.5    75.5    85
t1      95.75   95.5    75.5    85
t2      96.5    95.5    75.5    85
t3      96.5    95.5    75.5    85
t4      96.5    95.5    75.5    85
...     ...     ...    ...  ...
t9996   95.5    95      75.5    85.5
t9997   95.5    95      75.5    85.5
t9998   95.5    95      75.5    85.5
t9999   95.5    95      75.5    85.5
t10000  95.5    95      75.5    85.5
```

I want to plot the 4 time series against the index. Using code:

```
df.plot(x = 'foo', y = '1')
```

I received this error:

```
KeyError: 'foo'
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on to the discussion, I am going to demonstrate three plotting methods (from most straightforward to least) using the first five points of your data frame.

Import libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
```

The sample dataframe

```
         1     2     3   4
foo                       
t0   95.00  95.5  75.5  85
t1   95.75  95.5  75.5  85
t2   96.50  95.5  75.5  85
t3   96.50  95.5  75.5  85
t4   96.50  95.5  75.5  85
```

#### Method 1

```
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

#### Method 2

```
df.reset_index().plot(x='foo')
plt.show()
```

#### Method 3

```
plt.plot(df.index,df)
plt.legend(df.columns)
plt.xlabel(df.index.name)
plt.show()
```

#### Output (the same for all methods)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use this. If `x` argument isn't provided, `DataFrame.plot()` takes `df.index` as default.

```
df.plot(y='1')
```

Comment: Hi @Reuben thank you for helping. I received `KeyError: '1'`. Do you know why?

Comment: @nilsinelabore You recieve the error if '1' is not a column name in the dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

```
plt.plot(df.index,df['1'])
```

Comment: Hi @Vinod thanks for your answer. I received `KeyError: '1'`. Do you know why?

Comment: '1' is not the column name in your dataframe, Solution to this would be using iloc which does not take column by its name but by index as follows,  plt.plot(df.index,df.iloc[:,1])